# Error building Windows Phone 8.1 unit test in VS Online

Tags: windows-phone-8, msbuild, azure-devops

I just set up a Windows Phone 8.1 project using VS 2013 update 2 and added it to a git repo in VS Online.

After configuring a build definition, I tried to run the build but it is erroring out on:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (1864): Could not find SDK "MSTestFramework, Version=12.0".
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (1864): Could not find SDK "TestPlatform, Version=12.0
```

The documentation for VS Online states that the WP8 SDK is installed, but there is no mention of WP8.1. http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/hosted-build-controller-vs.aspx#software

Has anybody managed to get a WP 8.1 unit test project to build, and run the tests using VS Online?